# how to simulate typing the backspace button

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all here is my project, note that CSS I am working on last so its not pretty.

shawnwow.com/chineseCharacterHelpr/

In the box if you type a couple characters, or say, "mao" and you will see some possible choices and you can type 1-5 to choose whichever choice you need. This is the default behavior of the module I downloaded from here:

http://yuhanz.github.io/chinese-ime.html

So now on to my project; if you click the hint button you will have some choices pop up. If you click on any of the Chinese characters in the boxes above the "play sound" button, you will see that it took the Chinese character and correctly placed it in the text box at the top. The step I am missing is I need for the selection to stay in there but the "mao" and the possible Chinese characters to go away as you have selected the character you want and are ready to move on to the next word.

I have been able to achieve this by clicking off the "phonetic typing" check box and checking it on again, it seems to clear the search out, just like I wanted. I tried to do this programmatically after a character is chosen and it didn't work.

```
$('.chinese-checkbox input').attr('checked', false); 
$('.chinese-checkbox input').attr('checked', true);
```

I tested I was affecting the correct checkbox by only commenting out the true and it did mark it as false when I selected a Chinese character. But for some reason that didn't delete the "mao" or its search like the manually checking off and back on the checkbox. If someone knows what I am doing wrong there that may also be a solution. That option is only there because I hoped this would work, I will hide the check box if I can get it to work and remove the checkbox if I can't. There should never be a reason for the user to change it.

Lastly, and finally bringing in the title, I found that if I just deleted the characters in the search box manually it would all disappear; but if I kept deleting it would start deleting what I had chosen before. If I just did a .empty on the .typing span that had the "mao" it would delete the characters but that's it, it would still leave the Chinese and the values in the JS. So I tried to delete them programatically. I used:

```
$('#chinese-ime .typing').text().length;
```

to get the number of characters in the box (so I know how much to delete) and if I can just use jQuery to get the focus on that box and then hit the backspace that many times, that would also clear out the box.

Comment: Please try to provide [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Be specific and concise about your problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I basically just need to know how replicate a keypress with JavaScript. In this case I need to focus on a certain input and then have the backspace key pressed x number of times.